# Has anyone tried installing Magento 2 with php-7?

Tags: magento2, installation, php-7

As php-7 and Magento 2 has been released, i was wondering, what are the configurations and dependencies that needs to keep in mind while installing Magento 2 on php-7?
What are some drawbacks and benefits of doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like now no problem to install Magento2 with php7, especially on linux platform

Best Benefits is performance

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I've found so far is if you plan to use Memcached for your session storage.  I had things plugged in and was getting a breaking error when I tried to log into the admin panel.  Check out my [post here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95225/session-regenerate-id-in-magento-2-with-php-7) for a temporary work around though.

Also, like KAnday already mentioned, the biggest thing is performance.  PHP 7 has a much smaller memory footprint and is fast on par with HHVM (HipHop Virtual Machine).  Check out [this blog article](https://www.besthostnews.com/php-5-6-vs-hhvm-3-7-vs-php-7-benchmarks/) if you want to see some benchmarks for PHP 5.6 vs HHVM vs PHP 7.